# How to delete system generated files in windows

Tags: windows

My home directory C:\ contains folders like this which are not deletable

```
13-01-2011  09:07    <DIR>          347c013006e03cf550b7b5d843
16-12-2010  18:01    <DIR>          8173aed3d93d759f96d8
25-06-2010  17:50    <DIR>          876b5ddc61ff0014417a6cefe8ab039e
09-02-2011  15:28    <DIR>          8f25e730f837c97c337660c4939a0274
16-09-2010  09:03    <DIR>          96dd5c0cb0d2626e6576982d23569c
11-05-2011  13:31    <DIR>          ae90dacd0c4ec547e7b07a8253526a
```

I would prefer to remove these files, how should I do it?

Comment: These are usually fine to delete - if you have administrative privileges they shouldn't stop you - what error are you receiving?

Comment: You don't currently have permission to access this folder, is the error I am getting when I click on the directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just SHIFT+DEL to permanently delete them. It is safe. These are only the temporary extraction locations for Windows Updates, and should have been automatically deleted, but sometimes they just don't.

It is possible some files inside the folders may be locked (as in your case), and if so, you can either boot into safe mode to kill them or use [Unlocker](http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker/).